# how to check if a word is in a certain positon of a sentence

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a word (verb) appears at a certain positon of a sentence using regex.

```
keyword is "work"
verb is "going"
```

I want it return True if the verb appears before AND within 3 words(index) of the word "work"

Sentence 1: `"I am going to work"`
and
Sentence 2: `"I am going to be work"`

First sentence returns `True` because the verb is 1 word infront of the keyword.

Second sentence returns `True` because the verb is 2 word infront of the keyword.

Currently I know `matcher.start()` to return the index of the starting letter of the words, how can I find the index of a word in relative to the entire sentence?

Comment: Is your words always space separated?

Comment: Do you just want some function that checks the condition? Does it have to use regular expressions?

Comment: Split the sentence into words. Get the index of the verb in the list. Get the index of the keyword. Subtract.

Comment: I don't know whether this would work better, but what if you split the sentence into an array of words using `str.split(' ');` and then iterated through the array looking for the words and comparing their indexes? I think that would be more readable/simple than the regex solution.

Comment: always seperated by a space yes.

Comment: A regex *might* not be the best approach for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following regex can serve your need:

```
\bgoing(\s+\w+){0,3}\s+work\b
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/ReJ062yYnY

Java version of regex:

```
^.*?\\bgoing(\\s+\\w+){0,3}\\s+work\\b.*$
```

**Java Code:**

```
String re = "^.*?\\bgoing(\\s+\\w+){0,3}\\s+work\\b.*$";
String str = "I am going one two three work";
System.out.printf("Matches: %s%n", str.matches(re)); // true

str = "I am going one two three four work";
System.out.printf("Matches: %s%n", str.matches(re)); // false
```

#### Update: Since OP wants to check this against a list of verbs here is a non-regex based solution:

```
List<String> verbs = new ArrayList<String>(
          Arrays.asList(new String[]{"have", "going", "leaving"}));
String[] arr = str.split("\\s+"); // split words
int i;
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { // find word "work" and save the index
    if (arr[i].equals("work"))
        break;
}
boolean found = false;
for (int j=i-1; j>0 && j >= i-4; j--) { // go backwards and search your verbs
    System.out.printf("Finding: %s%n", arr[j]);
    if (verbs.contains(arr[j])) {
        found = true; // found it, break now
        break;
    }
}
System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", found);
```

Comment: can I do `String patternString = \\bgoing\\b(\\s+\\w+){1,3}\\s+\\bwork\\b; Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString); Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);` ?

Comment: Yes it is better to compile this regex and save the Pattern object.

Comment: If I have 2 verbs in a list List<String> verbs = new `ArrayList<String>(); verbs.add("going"); verbs.add("leaving");` what do you sugges to use to check both verbs?  @anubhava

Comment: If there are 2 verbs only or can there be infinite number of words in the verbs list?

Comment: Well I could add as much as I want, so i guess "a lot", is there a way to check if each one fit the requirment of being within 3 or closer?

Comment: Hmm alright, thanks for clarifying. A lot of verbs can make regex based solution problematic. And there can be sentence with 2 verbs also like: `He will have it working` What do you think of these cases?

Comment: It will look at the first verb and then as long as the next 3 words contain the keywords: work, working, then it will return True. Maybe this way is better.

Comment: Alright got you, in that I would propose a non-regex based answer also. GIve me few mins to build it and I will edit my post.

Comment: Thanks, one question. String[] arr = str.split("\\s+"); is arr suppose to be the sentence to be tested?

Comment: Right str is the sentence and arr is array of words.

Comment: The second word boundary is not needed! and the third too

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Agreed its not needed because of space char next to it. Let me edit it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: However OP ended up using non-regex version of the code (as per comments above).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 String w1 = "I am going to work";                                       
 String w2 = "I am going to be work";                                    
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bgoing\\b(\\s+\\w+){1,3}\\s+\\bwork\\b");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(w1);                                              
 Matcher m1 = p.matcher(w2);                                             
 if (m.find()) {                                                         
   System.out.println(true);                                           
 }                                                                       
 if (m1.find()) {                                                        
   System.out.println(true);                                           

  }
```

Comment: How much different is this answer from mine :)

Comment: I also do it,when come up here to post,see you have given.so upvoted:)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this regex should work:

```
"going(\s(\w+)){2}work"
```

Comment: "And within three words of" was the requirement; so you need to match zero, one or two - I.e. `{0,2}` instead of `{2}`.